# Rename App catalog site in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can we rename the App Catalog site in SharePoint Online? 
If no, can we delete it and recreate it ? 
When i tried to delete the existing one, i get file not found when trying to access App Catalog link from the SPO admin center. 
When i restored the deleted app catolog site, it asks me to create a new site (Great!!!) but once Clicking create! SPO automatically link the restored site.

Anyone has an idea about this please ??

Best regards, 
Ahmed BOUCHAALA

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean change the title of App Catalog site?

You could go to the App Catalog site-> Site Settings-> Title, Description, and Logo, then change the title of the site. Like this:

[image]